# Bootstrap table with: Filter Columns and Collapsable Rows

Tags: html-table, django-templates, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-table

In this Django Project, I attempting to create a Bootstrap Table with collapsible rows and filter columns.  I've managed to make the collapsable rows work perfectly, but the column filtering is not working at all.

The filter columns are not working, the select fields are visible and drop downs for selecting work, but when an item is selected, the table does not filter.  I'm curious if I'm not using the object values correctly?

Bootstrap5 CDN is included in the _base.html header

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

This is the full code:

```
<!-- templates/post_list.html -->

{% extends "_base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container">
    <a class="jy-btn-text" href="{% url 'post_new' %}"><div class="yj-btn">Post New Job</div></a>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="table-wrapper">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="jy-text">Current Job Posts</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="table-responsive">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="extensions/filter-control/bootstrap-table-filter-control.css">
            <script src="extensions/filter-control/bootstrap-table-filter-control.js"></script>
            <!--
            <link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.21.4/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.7.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.21.4/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.21.4/dist/extensions/filter-control/bootstrap-table-filter-control.min.js"></script>
            -->
                <table class="table table-sm" id="postTable" data-filter-control="true" data-show-search-clear-button="true">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col"><h6 class="jy-text">  <h6></th>
                            <th scope="col"><h6 class="jy-text">Date<h6></th>
                            <th scope="col" data-field="title">
                                <div class="th-inner"><h6 class="jy-text">Title<h6></div>
                                <div class="fth-cell">
                                    <div class="filter-control">
                                        <!--<input type="search" class="form-control bootstrap-table-filter-control-name search-input" stryle="width: 100%;" placeholder value>-->
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm bootstrap-table-filter-control-title" style="width: 100%;" placeholder="" data-input="true" data-field="title">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" data-field="position">
                                <div class="th-inner"><h6 class="jy-text">Position<h6></div>
                                <div class="fth-cell">
                                    <div class="filter-control">
                                        <select class="form-control form-control-sm bootstrap-table-filter-control-position" style="width: 100%;" data-input="true" data-field="position">
                                            <option value></option>
                                            <option value="{{ post.position }}">Captain</option>
                                            <option value="Mate">Mate</option>
                                            <option value="ETO">ETO</option>
                                            <option value="Chief Engineer">Chief Engineer</option>
                                            <option value="Secdon Engineer">Secdon Engineer</option>
                                            <option value="Engineer / Deckhand">Engineer / Deckhand</option>
                                            <option value="Chef">Chef</option>
                                            <option value="Sous Chef">Sous Chef</option>
                                            <option value="Chief Steward(ess)">Chief Steward(ess)</option>
                                            <option value="Second Steward(ess)">Second Steward(ess)</option>
                                            <option value="Deckhand / Steward(ess)">Deckhand / Steward(ess)</option>
                                            <option value="Deckhand">Deckhand</option>
                                            <option value="Estate Staff">Estate Staff</option>
                                            <option value="Other">Other</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col"><h6 class="jy-text">Type<h6></th>
                            <th scope="col"><h6 class="jy-text">Location<h6></th>
                            <th scope="col"><h6 class="jy-text">LOA<h6></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {% for post in post_list %}
                        <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#hidden-row-{{ post.id }}">
                            <td>
                                <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><p class="jy-text">+</p></button>
                            </td>
                            <td scope="row"><p class="jy-text">{{ post.date_post }}</p></td>
                            <td scope="row"><p class="jy-text">{{ post.title }}</p></td>
                            <td scope="row"><p class="jy-text">{{ post.position }}</p></td>
                            <td scope="row"><p class="jy-text">{{ post.employment }}</p></td>
                            <td scope="row"><p class="jy-text">{{ post.location }}</p></td>
                            <td scope="row"><p class="jy-text">{{ post.vessel_size }}</p></td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- Hidden Row -->
                        <tr id="hidden-row-{{ post.id }}" class="collapse">
                            <td colspan="7" class="hiddenRow">
                                <p class="jy-text">Description: {{ post.description }}
                                <p class="jy-text">Contact this job!</p>
                                <a href="mailto:{{ post.email }}"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-phone fa-2xs"></i></a> <a href="tel:{{ post.phone }}"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-envelope fa-2xs"></i></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
  (function() {
    $('#postTable').bootstrapTable({
      filterControl: true,
      showSearchClearButton: true,
      filterShowClear: true,
      onPostBody: function() {
        // Initialize filter controls for 'title' and 'position' columns
        $('.bootstrap-table-filter-control-title').selectpicker();
        $('.bootstrap-table-filter-control-position').selectpicker();
      }
    });
  });
</script>

<!-- Collapsable rows -->
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var rows = document.querySelectorAll('.table tbody tr[data-toggle="collapse"]');
  rows.forEach(function(row) {
    row.addEventListener('click', function() {
      var target = this.getAttribute('data-target');
      var hiddenRow = document.querySelector(target);
      var display = window.getComputedStyle(hiddenRow).display;
      hiddenRow.style.display = (display === 'none') ? 'table-row' : 'none';
    });
  });
});
</script>


{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using bootstrap tables, I suggest you to use Datatables (https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap5.html). I hope it is helpfull, not only filter you can do pagination, sorting etc. Checkout more examples from the same link above.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion.  I haven't found concise documentation in datatables for filtering columns with a drop down.  Any suggestions on where to find documentation on this?  I'm trying to stay away from an API, as I don't really think it's necessary for this project.